# h2 persistent storage: No database found

Tags: playframework, h2, playframework-1.x

H2 should create the database if it does not exist.  I modified the url changing 'mem' to 'file' and changing the next parameter 'play' to a path suffixed with a new name that is to become the database.  I keep getting this exception however:

```
Database error
A database error occured : No database found. Check the configuration of your application.

play.exceptions.DatabaseException: No database found. Check the configuration of your application.
    at play.db.DB.getConnection(DB.java:65)
    at play.modules.siena.PlayConnectionManager.getConnection(PlayConnectionManager.java:16)
    at play.modules.siena.SienaPlugin.onApplicationStart(SienaPlugin.java:138)
    at play.plugins.PluginCollection.onApplicationStart(PluginCollection.java:525)
    at play.Play.start(Play.java:526)
    at play.Play.detectChanges(Play.java:630)
    at play.Invoker$Invocation.init(Invoker.java:198)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at play.db.DB.getConnection(DB.java:58)
```

this is the active environment:

```
%h2dev.application.mode=dev
%h2dev.db.url=jdbc:h2:file:/var/stkdb/h2.db;MODE=MYSQL;LOCK_MODE=0
%h2dev.jpa.ddl=create
%h2dev.mail.smtp=mock
```

Any ideas?  I have the GAE module installed too.  That should not matter though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following lines to your `application.conf`:

```
%h2dev.db.driver=org.h2.Driver
%h2dev.db.user=sa 
%h2dev.db.pass=
```

Comment: I needed only the line %h2dev.db.driver=org.h2.Driver .. Perhaps a good exception from the framework is in order.

Comment: strange how the h2 "mem" database worked fine, but when I moved h2 to the file system the driver configuration line was required.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned on the list - you cannot use a filesystem DB on GAE.  If your intent is to get this working for testing/development only, then perhaps this will work.  If you want to deploy this code on GAE you are heading down a dead-end because you'll never be able to use H2 on GAE.

Comment: I intend to run on h2 in Amazon today and remain as compatible with the data-store in the future.  Should this run better in GAE and we need auto-scaling.

Comment: Perhaps disable the GAE module and see if that helps - you should be able to continue to use Sienna.  I'm not certain, but it may effect how the HPA Plugin loads.

Comment: was a lot of code changes, but I just tried that .. thank you .. no luck though

Comment: sorry for the wild goose chase. :(  one final comment that may be useful - be careful about believing you can easily switch to GAE's datastore and have it work similar fashion to H2 - there are many extreme differences in performance between H2 and GAE's HRD (HRD is really slow!), and also how they behave (ACID vs BASE : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency )

Comment: I agree completely .. I gained some experience on GAE first to help with that.  Also, I'm using DAO so I have hopefully confine it to a single layer for changes...

Comment: Ah, cool, I just wanted to warn you.  I spent over a year trying to handle the idiosyncrasies of GAE and eventually bailed on it because the platform itself was unstable (post-beta) and the support left you wondering what was going on.  Now I just run a postgres server on AWS and web-apps on any other scalable server (heroku/appfog/cloudbees/openshift/...) - hopefully someday I'll care more about 1M users on my database, but not yet. :)